# RecyclerView вывод данных по условию

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Имею адаптер `RecyclerView` в который передаю `ArrayList<MyList>`.
`ArrayList<MyList> myList;`

В `onBindViewHolder` проверяю условие

```
if(myList.isShown) //показываю данные.
```

Например в `myList` 100 записей, 5 из которых `myList.isShown == true`.
`RecyclerView` где `myList.isShown == true` выводит данные,а где `myList.isShown == false` выводит пустые яцейки.Как вывести только нужные ячейки?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно каждый раз формировать новый список из необходимых и на `getCount()` возвращать его `size()`.

Например вот так (в адаптере):

```
ArrayList<MyList> listShown;

void createListForShow(ArrayList<MyList> listAll){
    listShown = new ArrayList<MyList>();
    for (int i=0;i<listAll.size();i++)
        if (listAll.get(i).isShown) listShown.add(listAll.get(i));
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {            
    return listShown.size();
}
```

Comment: Я так и сделал просто думал можно по другому.А то потихоньку память жирет.Я еще пробовал удалять записи но удаляет ровно половину,хотя по условию должно остаться 3 шт

Comment: возможно есть способ оптимальней. Тоже будет интересно его узнать :) но навскидку - как-то так. Можно попробовать делать `ViewHolder.visibility` = `GONE`, но я не уверен в эффекте и эффективности)

Comment: Делал.Выводится весь список только где условие не совпало выходит пустую ячейку.

Comment: @Ivan, какая память, у Вас список размером в миллиард что ли? Без дополнительного списка можно ограничить показ, если список отсортирован так, что сначала идут все с `isShown == true`, потом остальные, тогда в `getItemCount()` можно вернуть число нужных элементов и остальные адаптер показывать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен поможет ли вам это решение, но есть интересный метод:

P.S - прошу прощения, но код на kotlin, уже даже забыл как эти методы на java выглядят =)) но думаю разница не особо сильная.

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val item = mItems.get(position);
    if (item.visible == true) {
       return 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

А в методе onCreateViewHolder делаем так:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): BaseVH? {
    val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
    if (viewType == 1) {
        return CustomVH(inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_here, parent, false))
    }
    return null
}
```

в onBindViewHolder нужно holder на нуль проверять, если не нуль то заполнять данными.

С null не проверял, но если будет ругаться на то что нельзя null holder возвращать, то можно просто пустой holder возвращать с 0 высотой view.
Недавно копался с LayoutManagerom и разные способы пробовал и точно знаю что с 0 высотой места не занимает, или View.GONE как вариант.

А вообще метод onBindViewHolder нужен для заполнения данными, а в него уже переход после onCreateViewHolder, тоесть вы как бы макет уже загрузили, но просто он пустой и поэтому занимает место.